# asp.net core does not work on Visual Studio 19

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, logging

When I install Visual Studio 2019 with ASP.NET Core, create a new project and run it, I get these messages:

> InvalidOperationException: Configuration value : 'Information' is not supported

> Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.TryGetSwitch(string value, out LogLevel level) //This message I got when I ran the project from the command line window (the black window).

I am learning ASP.NET Core with Visual Studio. Up to this week, everything worked properly. Then it stopped working. It happened a little time after I disabled logging (the build) messages to output window (I did this by menu - Tools->Options...->Debugging->Output Window : turning General Output Settings to off). In addition , a little time before, I updated Visual Studio according to an update notification that I got.

I uninstalled and downloaded Visual Studio and ASP.NET Core several times but I still have the problem and get these error messages.

The details of the software:

- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 version 16.8.3
- ASP.NET Core - I tried several versions including the latest version
- Windows 10

By the way, I do not have this file

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions
```

in Visual Studio or 'dotnet' libraries.

I will be glad to get any advice and to add more information as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Comment this code

```
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions.TryGetSwitch(string value, out LogLevel level) //This message I got when I ran the project from the command line window (the black window).
```

Right click your project. Manage NuGet packages and install Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.LoggerFilterConfigureOptions. Uncomment code. Run project

Comment: Thank you. I just create an empty ASP.NET Core Web Application project and I get this message. I don't have this line of code that you mentioned , just the line : "using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;" which I commented, and performed your suggestion. The problem still exists. Maybe the uninstalling is not performed well , so there is left some problematic code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem resolved.
It was a hard disk corruption.
After trying many options for solution it occurred to be a hard drive failure.
After several attempts to fix the disk it came to operate properly and now I can build and run projects on Visual Studio \ ASP.NET Core MVC.